# Unable to recover MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, error-handling, raspberry-pi, mariadb, webserver

So I was trying to get my web server setup on my pi by installing mariaDB and phpmyadmin. While doing so, I was going through and dropping tables, and found mysql. I accidently dropped it and lot 21 important files, and I can't seem to figure out how to recover this loss. Due to this, I'm unable to create any new users thanks to an error I created - 1064. Which puts me in a stall.

I've exhausted everything from uninstall to reinstall and nothing seems to give. Googling the issue hasn't been much of a resolve too.

Comment: That's what backups are for. MySQL doesn't have built-in recovery.

Comment: No database is safe from a root user that wildly issues `rm`/reinstall/google commands without understanding.